# Get language scores in CMU sphinx4

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to be able to predict the language of words in spoken speech and then use corresponding language and acoustic models in cmu sphinx
But I dont know where to look for language scores for each word

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx4 does not support language identification